# keep multiple SSH connections alive for future commands

Tags: linux, hadoop, ssh

I have a script to transfer large amount of files from a local machine to HDFS on a remote machine. In the script it uses `ssh` like this:

```
cat localfile | ssh user@remote 'hadoop fs -put - path-to-target-file'
```

Since I have a lot of files to transfer, and before each transfer I need to check whether there already exists a target file with the same name, thus for each transfer I have to use two ssh commands (check existence, put). Because establishing a SSH connection is time consuming, I'm wondering whether there are methods to keep the SSH connect alive so that after the first successful connection, other ssh commands do not try to establish a new connection but directly use the old one.

Also, I used multiple processes to do uploading. Is that possible to keep multiple, different connections alive? For example, if I use 4 processes, is is that possible to keep 4 different connections alive at the same time?

Thanks.

Comment: `scp` and `rsync` are your friends!

Answer (score 1):

This may not work with Hadoop, I don't know: Consider scripting an sftp session. `mput file*` is awesome.

Related: To keep alive a current session, this is handy in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
ServerAliveInterval 300
ServerAliveCountMax 60
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a wrong approach to begin with. Firstly, if SSH is passed a command to execute on the remote server like `ssh user@host "command"`, it *will* exit after the command execution.

You should consider using `sftp`, `scp` or `rsync`. The latter will satisfy your needs for checking remote versions and controlling if and when a target is overwritten by various conditions, and also to execute many file operations within one connection. Check out [Rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) website.

Comment: Thanks. I considered use `Rsync`, which is really awesome if I want to transfer to remote local file system. But later I went back to `ssh` because it can not execute a command (in my case, put the file to HDFS). Or I missed something, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could send operations to the server to prevent a connection loss due to inactivity.  This can be done by adding the following lines to ~/.ssh/config

```
    Host *
    ServerAliveInterval <seconds>
```

Where 'seconds' is the number of seconds before sending a no-op code.